# How to design tiers of ASP.NET MVC web application if it is to be hosted in DMZ with no direct access to database (tcp port 1433 blocked by firewall)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-web-api

Consider the following network security setup:

```
       Users         Internet
         |        
  ====Firewall==== Port 80, 443 only
         |              
     Web Server      DMZ - ASP.NET MVC + Web API
         |          
  ====Firewall==== Port 80, 443 only
         |         
     "App" Server   WCF or ASP.NET Web API ??
         |           
      Database      Internal network
```

I have seen the above network setup at many client premises. The IT infrastructure team doesn't allow web server in DMZ to establish direct connection to SQL Server hosted in internal network over port 1433. Irony is I've seen web.config lying around on web server with plain text DB passwords which they're OK with.

Usually I've seen and worked on solutions where a WCF is hosted on the "App" server (*as it can be used on HTTP ports*) as shown in the diagram. WCF becomes the only way for web frontend to interact with DB. One "benefit" of using WCF is that it returns strongly typed objects which are easy to consume from the ASP.NET MVC frontend.

Questions:

1. WCF is used because it allows data transfer on 80 or 443 and returns strongly typed objects. Is it a good choice?
2. Should ASP.NET Web API be used instead? If so, how to achieve strong typing with complex objects graphs? Are JSON.net and inbuilt serializers sufficient for the job?
3. Is there a better solution?

Please note that we cannot use ASP.NET Core at present.

Since this is a recurring problem, I'd really like to hear from community if there is better solution than using WCF.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, ASP.NET Core is *NOT* an option. WCF *cannot be used with binary protocol* as it requires ports *other than 80* which is very reason I'm asking this question. We can only use SOAP with WCF which is again HTTP and as you said "slower" so similar to Web API.

Comment: Also, this has NOTHING to do with load balancing. Load balancing doesn't involve restricting communication to HTTP ports.

Comment: That's precisely what I meant when I said that you didn't provide any of the requirements that could help you pick one or the other. Multi-tiered applications can be built using SOAP or REST. Just as easily. If you need SOAP (why?) you can't use Web API. If not, there's not enough info to choose.

Comment: Of course it has to do with load balancing and high availability. What you asked has nothing to do with port restrictions. You are asking the wrong questions. Multi-tiered applications can have *multiple* machines per tier. There can be *multiple* front-end web servers. There can be *multiple* back-end application servers. Typically you need two of both to ensure high availability.

Comment: I'm not talking about what you posted - there's not enough info. You didn't even say *why* you considered WCF. I'm talking about what you need to consider in order to decide. Security, API versioning, reliability, standards, ease of deployment, ease of maintenance. Caching - SOAP uses POST only so caching is *hard*. REST (Web API) uses POST only to modify data and GET to retrieve which makes caching *easy*.

Comment: *As shown in the diagram and mentioned in the question*, since ASP.NET mvc frontend CANNOT connect to database traditionally (over tcp port 1433 or customized) because of firewall restrictions, WCF is hosted on the app server and web frontend will call WCF over HTTP port (SOAP) to exchange data. That is the ONLY reason to select wcf, because we couldn't find any other solution. I'm asking this question to find out *if there any better solution.*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163947/discussion-between-ravi-m-patel-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: Maybe just host web api on internal server with database access and proxy everything to it from internet facing machine?

Comment: You can host the ASP.NET MVC app in APP server layer. Then in WEB server layer, set up a reverse proxy using IIS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just done a system with the same issue, DB access is restricted to an App server.

The method we chose to employ was an Mvc front end and a Web Api back end hosted on the App Server.

To get the strong typing that you would typically get over WCF, we opted for a tool called Refit: https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit.  It allows you to turn an interface with a pre-configured url template into an object you can inject via a normal DI container, making it very testable and removing a lot of the boilerplate HttpClient code.  This works really well with a WebApi back end.

Comment: Web API also provides strong typing. An action parameter can be a string or a compelx object. Refit provides an alternative for WSDL and proxy generators.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm going to explore this option.

Answer (score 4):

Build [IIS Reverse Proxy](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps/) to your DMZ area and you do not need two separate servers (web+app). When reverse proxy routes all relevant traffic to your web server, you can run it in internal network.

```
    Users           Internet
     |        
====Firewall====  Port 80, 443 only
     |              
IIS Reverse Proxy     DMZ 
     |          
====Firewall====  Port 80, 443 only
     |         
  Web Server        ASP.NET MVC
     |           
  Database       Internal network
```

Comment: Thanks, I explored this option before asking this question. I've requested my infrastructure team to consider this option. However, from my past experiences with them, it is highly unlikely that they will make any changes so I'm looking for a best solution for the current network setup.

Comment: As you can see, there is no need to change network setup. Firewall and network segments remain same since reverse proxy can use those common ports (80,443) when communicating to actual web server in private network, but of course you can change ports also if needed for some reason. With reverse proxy, mplementation is much easier since you do not need to implement your own software-proxy-layer. Of course reverse proxy configuration can have it’s own challenges (with gzip encodings etc) but there are bunch of guidance and support in web.

Comment: I agree, but Infosec team has to agree too.

Comment: Ok, let’s hope that some day your infosec team finds this answer as accepted and then they are convinced themselves :) But yeah, I can try to find more arguments if there is some exact functional or security-related problem pointed out with reverse proxy config.

Answer (score -1):

I would do the following setup:

```
          Users         Internet
                   |        
            ====Firewall==== Port 80, 443 only
                   |              
         {Proxy/load balancer with URL pattern rules} 
            |                    |
http://foo.com/api/...        http://foo.com/ui/...
            |                    | 
            |          {static content server} 
            |
            |          
     ====Firewall==== Port 80, 443 only
            |         
        "App" Server   ASP.NET Web API 
            |           
         Database      Internal network
```

- Static content server might be MVC application(s) without a need to access DB
- URL pattern rules might be replaced to different domains (e.g. foo.com and api.foo.com)